# How to overlay audio file on .wmv video file using c#?

Tags: c#, directshow

I want to record video and audio files using C#. After recording of audio + video i want to merge them. There can be only one video file and 10 audio file. I want this ten files to overlay on one video file.

I am assure that i want video file in .wmv format. Can you tell me i should record audios in which format so later i can overlay those audio files on .wmv format video file?

Also please let me know how to overlay audio file on .wmv video file?

Hope i will get prompt reply for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use DirectShow Editing Services (DES) to do it. DirectShowLib should provide DES support in C#. Using it, create a timeline with video group (1 track) and audio group (several tracks if you need to overlay/mix some audios, i.e. hear more than one at a time). Place your video and audio files on the timeline in desired positions. Then tell DES to create a DirectShow graph and you'll get one video and one audio output pin. Connect them to ASF writer to save result to WMV.